# Transform String data into numbers (where string should be always the same number), with the ability to transform them back

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to build a Machine Learning solution, predicting upcoming sales per product.

The dataset is containing thousand products (which are represented as a string. E.g., ‘Product_1_12345’).

Since the product information is essential for the modelling (would like to forecast, on product level), I tried different approaches (among others creating dummies).

However, since this was causing too many columns, I am exploring an alternative. What I would like to have:

```
Original_Product_ID      New_Product_ID
Product1_ABC                1
Product4_ABC                2
Product1_ABC                1
Another_Product             3
Product4_ABC                2
```

**The goal is to assign each unique string, to a number**. But if we have that product later again, I would like to have the same number.

Later on, I would like to **convert the numbers back to Original** Product ID.

Does anyone know how to do this? A dictionary doesn’t look like a solution, since I need to fill it in automatically (and I have thousands of products).

Comment: use `pandas.factorize` to assign a unique identifier to each unique ID. factorize outputs both the factors and the list if you want to reconstitute the original variables later on

Comment: maybe I closed a bit too fast, I'll add the method to map back the IDs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert you can use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

This function output both the factors as numpy array **and the unique IDs in order of the factors**.

You can save both and use this unique ID list to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) back the original IDs later on:

```
factors, ids = pd.factorize(df['Original_Product_ID'])

df['New_Product_ID'] = factors

# map the original IDs
df['Original_ID_from_factor'] = df['New_Product_ID'].map(dict(enumerate(ids)))
```

output:

```
  Original_Product_ID  New_Product_ID Original_ID_from_factor
0        Product1_ABC               0            Product1_ABC
1        Product4_ABC               1            Product4_ABC
2        Product1_ABC               0            Product1_ABC
3     Another_Product               2         Another_Product
4        Product4_ABC               1            Product4_ABC
```